# Average calories of "moderate" food

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I keep a spreadsheet with caloric information about food. Each row represents a product labelled as {negative, small, moderate} and the number of calories.

I included a shared copy of the spreadsheet.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzZ1B.png)

[Shared table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1We5YYO2pgbkkD4AYFB2CdJ9E9xqUNZAcFzWoR4QW4m8/edit)

I would like to calculate the average of the numbers that are in the same row as the keyword 'moderate'. For instance, I would like to obtain something like (890+914+731+1159+789)/5=897. I have tried =AVERAGE(B3,B7:B10) and it works but it needs to be modified when I add another product.

The expected output is in red. I want to obtain such output using formulas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can also consider the use of AVERAGEIF() as it seems the function is built for situations like this:

```
=averageif(A2:A; "moderate"; B2:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert new row, formula will be modified automatically. Also, your formula is wrong, missing semicolon:

```
=AVERAGE(B3; B7:B10)
           ^
```

Comment: That depeends on locale, on some places it is a semicolon, and others it is the just the comma. Also, the formula not always update to new rows, the selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use a `IF Statement`. Then you automatically do the average of the numbers `IF` the respective value is `moderate`. This is better, because it will work, if you have 5 or 5000 `Moderates`

Just use: `=AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:B10;(A2:A10="moderate")))`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) with [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en), it's a more basic formula, not as powerful as `FILTER`, but just as funcitonal. Also to use unlimited ROWs, you can remove the number on the second part of the RANGE, this for any formula, in this case your formula would be as such:

`=SUMIF(A2:A;"moderate";B2:B)/COUNTIF(A2:A;"moderate")`